# Undefined reference when using TShark C++ source file to dissect a message after adding the required libraries

Tags: c++, qt, wireshark, tshark, wireshark-dissector

I want to use TShark source files to dissect a message (e.g rrc sib 3 message) in C++. I have done the following steps:

1. Download `wireshark-2.6.6.tar.xz` and go to the extracted folder.
2. `sudo ./configure --prefix=/home/***/build/`
3. `sudo make -j 8`
4. `sudo make install`
   (After that I have a *build* folder which is contains *bin*, *include*, *lib*, *share* folders.)
5. Open C++ ide (Qt) and add the following libs:

   ```
    LIBS += -L/home/***/build/lib/ -lwireshark \
           -L/home/***/build/lib/ -lwiretap \
           -L/home/***/build/lib/ -lwsutil \
           -L/home/***/build/lib/ -lwscodecs
   ```
6. Of course I include the path like this:

   ```
    INCLUDEPATH += /home/***/build/include/wireshark
    DEPENDPATH += /home/***/build/include/wireshark
   ```
7. And also the wireshark source folder which I downloaded in step 1:

   ```
   INCLUDEPATH += /home/***/wireshark-2.6.6
   DEPENDPATH += /home/***/wireshark-2.6.6
   ```
8. Open TShark.c file (/home/***/wireshark-2.6.6/tshark.c) in Qt.

After these steps, it seems that every thing should be OK, but I have undefined reference to about 70 functions that I think I should add some other libs in step 5.

A part of my code (`tshark.c`) is as follows:

```
...
...
...
static int
real_main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   ...
   initialize_funnel_ops();
   return exit_status;
}
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   return real_main(argc, argv);
}
...
...
...
```

The `initialize_funnel_ops()` function which is in `/build/include/wireshark/epan/funnel.h` gives this error:

```
error: undefined reference to `initialize_funnel_ops'
```

This error apears for some other funtions too.

So how can I solve it? Should I add a new library? Or did I make a mistake in adding the libraries and the path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Try to link with *libtshark.so* library, too. If the library does not exist, try to add the option *--enable-tshark* to *configure*.

Comment: @WernerHenze thanks, I know the reason of this error. I think I need another libraries and the link which you specified does not solve my problem.

Comment: @RomhaKorev thank you very much, but after configuring with --enable-tshark, no library was created and I could not add it to my program. Do you know why not creating it?

Comment: @RomhaKorev --enable-tshark is set by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top-level Wireshark [CMakeLists.txt](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=CMakeLists.txt;h=600406c66de5172dd1104a1f9945497f8e1165d2;hb=HEAD#l2281) file should help you figure out what libraries and files `tshark` needs.  One of the dependencies is [`${TSHARK_TAP_SRC}`](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=CMakeLists.txt;h=600406c66de5172dd1104a1f9945497f8e1165d2;hb=HEAD#l1598), which includes `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ui/cli/tap-funnel.c`, and [tap-funnel.c](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=ui/cli/tap-funnel.c;h=c7babc74a28f02a84160772734cf4df7931feb5e;hb=HEAD#l110) is the file where `initialize_funnel_ops()` is defined.

Comment: Thanks, after adding `#include <ui/cli/tap-funnel.c>` the error for that function was solved. Is it a right way to include c files in my code to solve all of the similar errors?

Comment: That's not really the right way to compile multiple source files into 1 binary.  Have a look at your compiler's manual, man pages for more information about how to do this, but as a quick example assuming gcc is your compiler, you might use `gcc file1.c file2.c ... fileN.c -o myprogram`.  This doesn't really scale very well though, so normally Makefiles are used to help with this.  But since Wireshark uses cmake now, you might also want to look into using that.